# Subsetting a data by date range/days in R

Tags: r, date, subset

I am trying to subset data from ONLY the following specific weekdays "Thu", "Fri", and "Sat" from the 'Date' variable in my data set.

```
> head(tidyFile)
            Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
66637 2007-02-01 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128  243.15              1.4
66638 2007-02-01 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130  243.32              1.4
66639 2007-02-01 00:02:00               0.324                 0.132  243.51              1.4
66640 2007-02-01 00:03:00               0.324                 0.134  243.90              1.4
66641 2007-02-01 00:04:00               0.322                 0.130  243.16              1.4
66642 2007-02-01 00:05:00               0.320                 0.126  242.29              1.4
      Sub_metering_1 Sub_metering_2 Sub_metering_3
66637              0              0              0
66638              0              0              0
66639              0              0              0
66640              0              0              0
66641              0              0              0
66642              0              0              0
```

I used the following code to subset between a date range that I needed:

```
tidyFile <- newFile[newFile$Date >= "2007-02-01" & newFile$Date <= "2007-02-02", ]
```

But there might be something wrong with the way I subset because when I call "Thurs", "Fri", and "Sat" in this subset, I get NA values, which can't be right. Should I have done something with the times to ensure I'm inclusive of the dates above?

Finally, I need to further subset my data by "Thurs", "Fri", and "Sat" and I can't seem to do that. I've tried the following:

```
library(lubridate)
with(tidyFile[wday(tidyFile, label=T) == "Thurs" & "Fri" & "Sat"])
```

An error message is returned:

```
Error in wday(tidyFile, label = T) : unused argument (label = T)
```

UPDATE

These are the steps I've taken to create my script:

```
## STEP 1: Set working directory
setwd("/Users/usaid/datasciencecoursera/data/") 

## STEP 2: Create a new object 'newFile' and read .txt file into R
newFile <- read.table("course_4_proj_1.txt", header=TRUE, sep=";", na.strings = "?", nrows= 1000000, stringsAsFactors=FALSE,  as.is=TRUE)  

## STEP 3: Create a new object 'newFile$Date' and format dates (into date class)
newFile$Date <- as.Date(newFile$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y") 
newFile$Date <- strptime(newFile$Date, format = "%d/%m/%Y", tz = "")

## STEP 4: Create a new object 'tidyFile' and subset data based on date range provided in Project 1 instructions
tidyFile <- newFile[newFile$Date >= "2007-02-01" & newFile$Date <= "2007-02-02", ] 

## STEP 5: Subset data by "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat"
library(lubridate)
with(tidyFile, wday(Date, label = TRUE))
days <- with(tidyFile, wday(Date, label = TRUE) %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat"))
tidyFile[days, ]
```

When I run Step 5, I get the error message I mentioned below.

Comment: Your boolean condition isn't correct. You probably want to use `%in%`.

Comment: Where would %in% be included in the code above?

Comment: If you want any of the weekdays Thur, Fri or Sat, you'd do `... %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat")`.

Comment: I see. But I want the data from all three weekdays.

Comment: Yes, exactly my point.

Comment: I tried this: `with(tidyFile[wday(tidyFile, label=T) == %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat")]` Error message: `Error: unexpected SPECIAL in "with(tidyFile[wday(tidyFile, label=T) == %in%"`

Comment: Drop the `==`, read `help("%in%")` for examples.

Comment: Now I have `with(tidyFile[wday(tidyFile$Date %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat")])` but that doesn't do it either. I tried following the examples, but I presume I've gone terribly wrong somewhere.

Comment: You've cycled through a variety of different incorrect code, some of which I haven't even touched upon yet. Your syntax of `with` is incorrect. You last attempt to fix your use of `%in%` radically changed the location of the parentheses. I think you really need to go back and work through some basic R tutorials and manuals for a while.

Comment: I've been pasting together code from several manuals and online tutorials and tried different iterations. I am a novice R user and am struggling to get the right string of code. I was hoping this forum would help me better understand what I'm doing wrong since the manuals and tutorials have not been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help with the flailing?

```
## snippet of your data, not all columns
dat <- read.table(text = "            Date     Time Global_active_power Global_reactive_power Voltage Global_intensity
66637 2007-02-01 00:00:00               0.326                 0.128  243.15              1.4
66638 2007-02-01 00:01:00               0.326                 0.130  243.32              1.4
66639 2007-02-01 00:02:00               0.324                 0.132  243.51              1.4
66640 2007-02-01 00:03:00               0.324                 0.134  243.90              1.4
66641 2007-02-01 00:04:00               0.322                 0.130  243.16              1.4
66642 2007-02-01 00:05:00               0.320                 0.126  242.29              1.4
", header = TRUE)

## Make Date an actual Date
dat <- transform(dat, Date = as.Date(Date))
## Load lubridate
require("lubridate")
```

Get `wday()` to return the day of the week for `Date`:

```
with(dat, wday(Date, label = TRUE))
```

Now we need to add to this the comparison with the options you listed. This is done using the `%in%` binary operator. The right-hand side of `%in%` needs a vector of things to match against, hence you need to put `c("Thurs", "Fri", "Sat")` to the right of `%in%`, as in:

```
with(dat, wday(Date, label = TRUE) %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat"))
```

With the snippet of data you showed you get

```
> with(dat, wday(Date, label = TRUE) %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat"))
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

To complete, you would need something like

```
take <- with(dat, wday(Date, label = TRUE) %in% c("Thurs","Fri","Sat"))
dat[take, ]
```

which is this case is all of them, but I presume in your real data set you more than these few records.

Comment: When I get to `with(dat, wday(Date, label = TRUE))` I get the following message `Error in wday(Date, label = TRUE) : unused argument (label = TRUE)`

Comment: *sigh* confirm that you are using `lubridate::wday()`. What does `?wday` tell you? `label` **is** an argument of the function, at least in the version I just installed from CRAN. Are you running up-to-date versions of the package? As you can see (as I gave a reproducible example and included the code and the generated output) this does work!

Comment: Okay, now it works! I think it was the way I was trying to load lubridate. I need to compare two variables: x (electricity usage) by days (Thurs, Fri, Sat). How do I call 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat' from what we did above? Apologies I'm so dense, but I'm learning.

Comment: Your aren't learning; about R or [so]. There is no `x` in your data. What do you mean by "How do I call 'Thurs', 'Fri', 'Sat'"? Sounds like you need to ask a new question on [so] but consider whether you should do as @joran suggested and go back over some introductory R material first?

Comment: Sorry. 'x' was just a generic term for a variable. The actual variable is Global_active_power from the dataset above. I want to plot the values of that variable against Date variable, but subsetting the Date to only include data for 'Thurs', 'Fri', Sat'. I think this is a better explanation.